# How to load multiple HTML from different functions of google script

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have a scenario where I load an 'first' html from doGet function then in that html I call google script function where I fetch some geocode then from this function I want to load different html file with some value. I tried something but that didn't worked for me. My google script looks like below,

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(e)
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('first');
  var htmlOutput = htmlTemplate.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  Logger.log('htmlOutput loaded')
  return htmlOutput;
}
function extractGeoCodes(excelRows){
    var latlng_arr = []
    for (var i = 0; i < excelRows.length; i++) {
    var add = excelRows[i]['Address']
    var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(add);
    latlng_arr.push(geocoder.results[0].geometry.location)
    Utilities.sleep(200);
    }
    var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('second');
    htmlTemplate.latlng_arr = latlng_arr;
    var htmlOutput = htmlTemplate.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
    Logger.log('second htmlOutput loaded')
    return htmlOutput;
}
```

My 'first' html looks similar to below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
    ></script>
<script>
    function Upload() {
        //This function uploads xlsx file and pass content to ProcessExcel
    };
    function ProcessExcel(data) {
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
            type: 'binary'
        });
        var firstSheet = workbook.SheetNames[0];
        var excelRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[firstSheet]);
        var latlng_data = google.script.run.extractGeoCodes(excelRows) //this calls google script function
    };
</script>
<body>

<p>Click on the "Choose File" button to upload a file:</p>
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" onclick="Upload()" />
<hr />
<div id="dvExcel"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

And 'second' html is,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var name = '<?= latlng_arr ?>';
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload=>
    <h1>Hello World, from Google cloud</h1>
    <div>
      <label>Value from latlong array = </label>
      <span><?= latlng_arr ?></span>
      <!-- we use the value from the variable which was set in the template in google script -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can see the log 'second htmlOutput loaded' but html is not loading it stuck at 'first'. How can I tackle this situation?

Comment: Your html?`````````````````​`````````````````

Comment: @TheMaster Both html files are added in question.

Comment: Use a querystring parameter to tell doGet() which page to return

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.withSuccessHandler()` to append to part of the page or use `document.write()` to clear the entire document. Since you'll be adding html as string, You should use [`.getContent`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#getContent()) on the `HtmlOutput`:

- Return string:

```
function extractGeoCodes(excelRows){
/*...*/
return htmlOutput.getContent();
}
```

- Html('second') stripped:

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var name = '<?= latlng_arr ?>';
    </script>
    <h1>Hello World, from Google cloud</h1>
    <div>
      <label>Value from latlong array = </label>
      <span><?= latlng_arr ?></span>
      <!-- we use the value from the variable which was set in the template in google script -->
    </div>
```

- First html handles string html:

```js
function addHtml(html){
  document.querySelector("body").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',html)
}
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addHtml).extractGeoCodes(excelRows) //this calls google script function
```